# assigning all properties of object A to the ones with the same name as object B

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I have two objects:

```
objectA = {
  valueOne: null,
  valueTwo: null
}
objectB = {
  valueZero: 'joe',
  valueOne 'john',
  valueTwo: 'jesse',
  valueThree: 'jessica',
  valueFour 'jojo'
}
```

I want two assign objectB property values to objectA properties but only those who have the same name. For example in our case objectA should become like this:

```
objectA = {
  valueOne: 'john',
  valueTwo: 'jesse'
}
```

How can I do it?

Comment: Please may you add your own attempt as a [mcve]?

Comment: I was adding an answer, since the duplicate doesn't quite work... `Object.fromEntries(Object.keys(objectA).map(key => [key, objectB[key]]))` --- This takes the keys of A, maps them to an array of key/value pairs, and then converts them back into an object.

Comment: Object.keys(objectB).forEach(key => { if (key in objectA) objectA[key] = objectB[key] });